# javascript sleep function with changing parameters

Tags: javascript

array moves contains just a couple of move I wanna draw on canvas. basically a deltaTime to sleep and a draw command.

This simply doesn't work :(

```
for (var i=0; i< parsed.moves.length; i++)
{
    var e = parsed.moves[i];
    setTimeout(function(){drawCmd(context,e)}, e.deltaTime*1000);

    //deltaTime are values btn 0-1, the sleep time i need to set btw commands 

 }  


function drawCmd(canvasctx, e)
{   

switch(e.type)
{
   //case ...
}
 }
```

it did nothing at all, not even calling drawCmd function

Comment: Where did you devine `deltaTime` value? Show us some more code.

Comment: That is `e` or `drawCmd`. You probably use them wrong.

Comment: nothing at all, i checked and it does reached the end of code, not calling drawCmd at all, and not sleeping at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code only delays all the `drawCmd` by `e.deltaTime*1000` and executes them all at once afterwards, all at `i = 10`

If you meant to "draw and wait, draw and wait", try this:

```
(function loop(i){
    var e = parsed.moves[i];      //e at current "i"

    if(i< parsed.moves.length){   //if not equal to length
        setTimeout(function(){
            drawCmd(context,e);   //draw in e.deltaTime*1000 milliseconds
            loop(++i);            //loop again
        }, e.deltaTime*1000);
    }

}(0));                            //start with i=0
```

Comment: ur my god @Joseph the Dreamer

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check the data type of deltaTime

```
    setTimeout(function () { }, undefined * 1000); // <- Executes imidiately
    setTimeout(function () { }, '1' * 1000); // <- Executes after 1 second
    setTimeout(function () { }, 1 * 1000); // <- Executes after 1 second
    setTimeout(function () { }, new Date() * 1000); // <- Executes after a long (i.e. 1337852997592 seconds) time
```

Comment: NB - All of your timeout instructions will be added to a queue that will begin to be processed **after** this function exits.  setTimeout is not a blocking call.